# Last Observation Carried Forward LOCF

Tags: excel

Is there a simple method for calculating Last Observation Carried Forward (LOCF) in Excel.

For example, in a clinical trial, if there are 8 scheduled events and the patient only attended 4, what is a simple method to calculate the Last Observation Carried Forward?

Answer (score 2):

Column A contains simple sequential numbers (1, 2, 3, 4, 5...)
Column B contains the observations (24, 23, , , 26...)
Column C contains a formula to calculate the Latest Populated Event

```
=IF(B2<>"",A2,"")
```

Column D contains a formula to calculate the Last Observation Carried Forward (LOCF)

```
=IFERROR(IF(B2<>"",B2,VLOOKUP(MAX(C$2:C2),A$2:B2,2,FALSE)),"")
```

Screenshots
[image: Screenshot showing formulas]
[image: Screenshot showing results]

Comment: an even more easier option would be to select all the blank cells using `Ctrl+G` and selecting `blanks` using `special` option. Write `=` sign in a single cell and select the values to be carried forward. Hit `Ctrl+Enter`. All the blank cells will be filled with their respective previous values.